# Prepend or append to values obtained from Knex js SQL queries

Tags: sql, node.js, knex.js

I have a simple `people` table which has two columns `id` and `name`.

I can query all the names along with the id as follows

```
const persons = await knex('people').select('id','name');
```

I want to add `Dr.` in front of all the names.

For example

```
{id:1, name: 'Tom'}
```

should return

```
{id:1, name: 'Dr. Tom'}
```

How do I do this in knex js ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could easily do it in memory using JS `map`, but apparently you want to do it on db level.

Basically, you need the following query:

```
select CONCAT('Dr. ', people.name) as 'name', people.id as 'id' from people;
```

(Tested in w3schools online fiddler)

So, effectively we could try the following (basing on **Identifier Syntax** from http://knexjs.org/):

```
knex({ people: 'people' })
  .select({
    id: 'people.id',
    name: 'CONCAT("Dr. ", people.name)'
  })
```

But I'm not sure if knex will substitute it properly.

The problem is, however, that `CONCAT` is not supported by all SQL dialects, as far as I am concerned.